# לפ"ד ש"פ Acronym deciphering

Tags: halacha, acronyms, vilna-gaon

In [Beur Hagra EH 7.14, SK 54](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=22248#p=90&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=), there is an Acronym I don't understand "ל"ד ש"פ". Can someone help me?

Comment: Perhaps consider the options [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34968&st=&pgnum=263) and [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34968&st=&pgnum=147)

Comment: לפי דבריו שפיר פירש?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "לפי דעת שאר פוסקים". He addresses the Poskim who state, against Rashi, that there is Zona from Chayave Lavin, as Rambam. Rashi holds that it's not the case. Thank you to @pcoz for deciphering the first part of the question.